# Call JavaScript function inside an different iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have 2 iframes inside an main html page and I would from iframe 2 call a javascript funcion located into iframe 1

At frame 2 I´m calling the function as showed bellow :

```
<tr class="style16" onclick="document.getElementById('IFRAME_mapa').changeCenter({lat:-20.419528,lng:-54.576573})">
```

And I´m getting this error message

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'changeCenter' of null

I also tried ..

```
<tr class="style16" onclick="document.getElementById('IFRAME_mapa').contentWindow.changeCenter({lat:-20.419528,lng:-54.576573})">
```

but got the same message saying about contentWindow can´t be read

The javascript function is located on iframe  section

First question.. is that what I´m trying to do possible ?
Second...what is correct way to do  this ?

Comment: Would be  simpler using [`postMessage API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to communicate between the various windows

Comment: *"but got the same message saying about contentWindow can´t be read"* That suggests the code trying to access it is in a different *origin* from the iframe. In which case, you can't do that. But we'd need to know more to be sure.

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder, so ..it meas I won´t be able to call a function from different iframe ?

Comment: @charlietfl researching about it

Comment: I did assume you controlled the code on both of these iframes. If not you will run into same origin policy restrictions

Comment: @charlietfl, can I move the javascript function to the main html file (one that calls the 2 iframe) and access the funcion ?

Comment: Yes... if you control the code in main page and iframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do and not using postMessage API

On caller iframe (iframe2), I call an JS function located at parent document

```
onclick="changeCenter({lat:-20.419528,lng:-54.576573})"
```

On parent has a function that recalls a function inside iframe1 passing parameter

```
function MapCenter(center) 
{
    document.getElementById("IFRAME1").contentWindow.changeCenter(center);
}
```

Finally inside iframe1  is the function that will execute the action on iframe1

```
function changeCenter(center) 
{
    map.setZoom(15);
    map.setCenter(center);
}
```